# Get parent Div and then the elements inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got some html (note this block of HTML is repeated with the data inside changing):

```
            <div class="memberDiv" style="position:relative">
                <p class="myUserName"><strong>Jo Bloggs</strong></p>
                <p class="myJobTitle">Widget Maker</p>
                <p class="myCountry">England</p>
                <button class="memberMore">MORE INFORMATION</button>
            </div>
```

And what I'm trying to do in java is get the actual values from inside the div (ie, Jo Bloggs, Widget Maker, England)

This is what I thought would work:

```
$(".memberMore ").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Get the 'parent' div (memberDiv)
    var myDiv = $(this).closest("div");
    alert($(myDiv).next(".myUserName").text());
    return false;
});
```

But the alert box is showing the 'undefined' error.

Could anyone spare me 5 minutes to show me the error of my ways please?

thanks,
Craig

Comment: Try alert(myDiv.find(".myUserName").text());

Comment: It's **well worth** your time reading through [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) beginning to end. It only takes an hour or two, and it pays that time back immediately. It's also incredibly useful to learn to use the debugger built into your web browser, so you can see exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**find()**](https://api.jquery.com/find/) instead

```js
$(".memberMore ").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //Get the 'parent' div (memberDiv)
  var myDiv = $(this).closest("div");
  console.log($(myDiv).find(".myUserName").text());
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="memberDiv" style="position:relative">
  <p class="myUserName"><strong>Jo Bloggs</strong>
  </p>
  <p class="myJobTitle">Widget Maker</p>
  <p class="myCountry">England</p>
  <button class="memberMore">MORE INFORMATION</button>
```

Comment: Fantastic work, thank you all. As soon as I can accept an answer I will. (You're all right though!)

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this
$(".memberMore ").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();        
    alert($(this).find(".myUserName").text());
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should you the "siblings" function, not the "find", like this:

```
$(".memberMore ").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();        
    alert($(this).siblings(".myUserName").text());
    return false;
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zfn6cg3y/)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when I replace this with myDiv (obviously I'm not expert in this!)

Comment: @SxChoc Strange! I've used the html you posted. Are you sure you've changed all references to classes and ids correctly? In the fiddle it looks like it's working...

Answer (score 0):

To return all paragraphs in that div, loop through them:

```js
$(".memberMore ").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //Get the 'parent' div (memberDiv)
  var myDiv = $(this).closest("div");
  var txtReturn = '';
  myDiv.find('p').each(function(index) {
    if (index>0) {
      txtReturn += ', '
    }
    txtReturn += $(this).text()
  });
  alert(txtReturn);
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="memberDiv" style="position:relative">
  <p class="myUserName"><strong>Jo Bloggs</strong></p>
  <p class="myJobTitle">Widget Maker</p>
  <p class="myCountry">England</p>
  <button class="memberMore">MORE INFORMATION</button>
</div>
```

Or you can make it slightly easier by moving the button out of the div, and/or changing it to `input type="button"` (so it has no inner text).

```js
$(".memberMore").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //Get the 'parent' div (memberDiv)
  var myDiv = $(this).prev("div");
  alert(myDiv.text());
  return false;
});
$(".memberMore2").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //Get the 'parent' div (memberDiv)
  var myDiv = $(this).closest("div");
  alert(myDiv.text());
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="memberDiv" style="position:relative">
  <p class="myUserName"><strong>Jo Bloggs</strong></p>
  <p class="myJobTitle">Widget Maker</p>
  <p class="myCountry">England</p>
  <input type="button" class="memberMore2" value="MORE INFORMATION" />
</div>
<button class="memberMore">MORE INFORMATION</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) function to get the text of all elements. If you need to get the string

`Jo Bloggs, Widget Maker, England`

You could do:

```js
$('.memberMore').on('click', function() {
  
  var text = $(this).siblings().map(function() {
    return $(this).text();  
  }).get().join(', ');
  
  alert(text);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="memberDiv" style="position:relative">
  <p class="myUserName"><strong>Jo Bloggs</strong></p>
  <p class="myJobTitle">Widget Maker</p>
  <p class="myCountry">England</p>
  <button class="memberMore">MORE INFORMATION</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the text of all `p`, you can try something like:

```
$(".memberMore ").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $(this).parent().find('p').each(function(index, elemt){
     console.log($(elemt).text());
  });

  return false;
});
```

The key here is the [parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) method.